# Сравнение значений ячеек

Tags: excel, сравнение

В экселе есть формула по сравнению значений ячеек друг с другом в одном столбце.
Скриншот примера приложен.
Подскажите плиз, как такую штуку можно реализовать в R?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно? Сравнить два значения?

Comment: да, сравнить два значения

Comment: Не скажу, как в *R*, в *Excel* можно проще: *=--(A4>A3)*

Comment: С Экселем-то все ясно, мне в R это надо сделать...

Answer (score 0):

```
#Создаем тестовый набор данных
df <- data.frame(vl = c(10, 20, 30, 3))

#в цикле со второй строки делаем проверку и результа записывам в столбец vl2
for(i in 2:nrow(df))
    df$vl2[i] <- ifelse(df$vl[i] > df$vl[i-1], 1, 0)
```

[image: Результат работы]